# How to disable sshd from boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and have installed openssh-server.

How do I disable/enable it from being started at boot time?

Apparently it is not done with `chkconfig`

```
# chkconfig --list|grep -i ssh
ssh                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough, even if you're using upstart (dependency-base booting):

```
update-rc.d ssh enable # sets the default runlevels to on
update-rc.d ssh disable # sets all to off
```

I didn't know Ubuntu included chkconfig by default, that's pretty interesting - Debian doesn't.

See the comment below on how to remove startup links - I'm not sure that works when using upstart though.

Comment: and update-rc.d -f ssh remove

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about removal. Are you sure this still works with upstart?

Comment: This disables the startup but if there is a current instance running, you still have to `service sshd stop` or your local equivalent. (I'm on Debian here.)

Answer (score 2):

There is not command I know of that can disable upstart jobs, but you can manually disable services by editing the corresponding Upstart configuration files. To stop SSHd from starting at boot time, comment out the line `start on ...` in `/etc/init/ssh.conf` as in:

```
description     "OpenSSH server"

#start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]
```